# How does Pyinstaller embed datas into exe file with --onefile option?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

When you build an exe file using --onefile option with Pyinstaller, you can specify datas (like picture or whatever...)

During the runtime, a tmp directory is created (MEI*) which contains python interpreter, your data in original format ...

How does Pyinstaller embed all theses datas?

.exe files are only machine code instructions right? They are not supposed to be "container file"...

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the pyinstaller manual?

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#id22

> How the One-File Program Works The bootloader is the heart of the
>   one-file bundle also. When started it creates a temporary folder in
>   the appropriate temp-folder location for this OS. The folder is named
>   _MEIxxxxxx, where xxxxxx is a random number.
>
> The one executable file contains an embedded archive of all the Python
>   modules used by your script, as well as compressed copies of any
>   non-Python support files (e.g. .so files). The bootloader uncompresses
>   the support files and writes copies into the the temporary folder.
>   This can take a little time. That is why a one-file app is a little
>   slower to start than a one-folder app.
>
> After creating the temporary folder, the bootloader proceeds exactly
>   as for the one-folder bundle, in the context of the temporary folder.
>   When the bundled code terminates, the bootloader deletes the temporary
>   folder.
>
> (In Linux and related systems, it is possible to mount the /tmp folder
>   with a "no-execution" option. That option is not compatible with a
>   PyInstaller one-file bundle. It needs to execute code out of /tmp.)
>
> Because the program makes a temporary folder with a unique name, you
>   can run multiple copies of the app; they won't interfere with each
>   other. However, running multiple copies is expensive in disk space
>   because nothing is shared.
>
> The _MEIxxxxxx folder is not removed if the program crashes or is
>   killed (kill -9 on Unix, killed by the Task Manager on Windows, "Force
>   Quit" on Mac OS). Thus if your app crashes frequently, your users will
>   lose disk space to multiple _MEIxxxxxx temporary folders.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_compression

Compressed data can be along with a decompression code into a single excutable.

So, Pyinstaller may include a runtime packer to do that.